# C - Histogram with shared values in additional output

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, histogram

A friend asked me to look at example questions for an introductory exam for his first year CS intro class and I'm a bit taken aback by one of the questions.

You're supposed to make a histogram of a 20 number array that contains values from 1 to 5, inclusive. Extremely straightforward stuff done in a few lines like the rest of the question, as one would expect. The point is to gauge existing knowledge of C basics in 10 short and simple questions problems or evaluate expect output of a small block of code, all on pen and paper.

Now that I've set the scene, in the second part of the question. For each two or more values that share the same frequency, print out an additional line stating the respective values and frequency.

For example, "The values 2, 4 and 5 occur 3 times each."

Now, I may be pretty rusty with my C, but wouldn't this require a substantial amount of extra code and logic for string building in comparison to the first part and the rest of the problems? Especially on a pen and paper 30 minute exam.

Just for the sake of it, the solution for the first part would simply be

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        histogram[nums[i]]++;
    }

for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Value %d appears %d times.\n", i - 1, histogram[i]);
    }
```

Comment: At it's simplest just need a nested loop. One way: Start with first `histogram` bucket, record it's index and value, if value is zero or one skip it, else zero out the value and then loop thru the rest of the array looking for the same value. If a same value is found then print out the index and zero out the value. Repeat the process for the next `histogram` bucket, etc. So probably no more than 10 lines of code.

Comment: Ideally if you keep the histogram in sorted order (or sort at the start of part 2), there isn't a whole lot of interesting logic. I don't see a way around the string manipulation, but even that isn't particularly hard.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that given 10 questions in 30 minutes, the second part is a little too time consuming. Perhaps it's the "time management" part of the test :)